# Ways of accessing foreign databases in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, foreign-keys

There are 2 known to me ways of accessing different, foreign DB in PostgreSQL.

1. `dblink`
2. `postgres_fdw`

Is there any possibility to run function (select-like) on foreign database and get its result (not using dblink)?

I know `dblink` has poor performance and creates multiple functions in asking db, which can impede keep organized with own functions. However, postgres_fdw can handle only tables (?)

Answer (score 0):

`postgres_fdw` can also handle views, so you could hide the function call behind a view in the foreign database:

```
CREATE VIEW fn_f AS SELECT * FROM f()
```

If you don't want to make changes to the foreign database, then I think you'll have to use `dblink`. I doubt that there will be much difference in terms of performance, if any.

Note that `postgres_fdw` also creates a few functions in the local database; if you're trying to keep things organised, consider installing extensions to a seperate schema.

Comment: Yeah, but views are building from not parameterized functions. I'd intend query like `SELECT a.id, b.name, database2.func(a.id, b.name) FROM...`